# AndroidViewModel onChanged is called after activity onCreate function?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that access a List of object of LiveData and i want to assign my variable to that list. Here is the code.

```
        chatViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication())).get(ChatViewModel.class);

        chatViewModel.getAllContactsForChat().observe(this, new Observer<List<UserContacts>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<UserContacts> userContacts) {
               Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, "inside", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                for(int i = 0; i<userContacts.size(); i++)
                {
                    UserContacts user = userContacts.get(i);
                    if(user.getId() == id)
                    {
                        firstName = user.getFirstName();
                        lastName = user.getLastName();
                        friendPublicKeyString = user.getFriendPublicKey();
                        profile = user.getPicture();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

This function is being called in onCreate of the ChatActivity. Now I noticed that the variable firstName, lastName, etc were being given null and my app kept on crashing. Upon debugging further I noticed that when ChatActivity onCreate is called this function is ignored and the main thread goes to next line and after some time it returns to this function and assign values. Now I want it to assign values on the very first run so my app can run normally. Here is the AndroidViewModel code.

```
public class ChatViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private ChatRepository chatRepository;

    private LiveData<List<UserContacts>> allContactsForChat;

    public ChatViewModel(@NonNull Application application) 
    {
        super(application);
        allContactsForChat = chatRepository.getAllContactsForChat();
    }
     public LiveData<List<UserContacts>> getAllContactsForChat()
    {
        return allContactsForChat;
    }
}
```

Here is ChatRepository code

```
public class ChatRepository {
    private ChatDao chatDao;

    private LiveData<List<UserContacts>> allContactsForChat;

    public ChatRepository(Application application)
    {
        ChatDatabase db = ChatDatabase.getInstance(application);

        chatDao = db.chatDao();

        allContactsForChat = chatDao.getAllContactsForChat();
    }

    public LiveData<List<UserContacts>> getAllContactsForChat()
    {
        return allContactsForChat;
    }
}
```

Here is ChatDao code

```
@Dao
public interface ChatDao 
{

    @Query("SELECT * FROM UserContacts")
    LiveData<List<UserContacts>> getAllContactsForChat();
}
```

Here is the crash log. I am converting the profile string to image and profile should be initialized inside onChanged. Since profile is not initialized the function is given null and this error occured.

```
2021-04-12 11:59:11.440 10151-10151/com.example.privatechatcopy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.privatechatcopy, PID: 10151
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.privatechatcopy/com.example.privatechatcopy.ChatActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference
        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:120)
        at com.example.privatechatcopy.NameAndImage.stringToImage(NameAndImage.java:162)
        at com.example.privatechatcopy.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:168)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: were being given null and my app kept on crashing. - please add crash log.

Comment: @parthpatibandha I have pasted crash log.

Comment: public ChatViewModel(@NonNull Application application) 
    {
        super(application);
        chatRepository = ChatRepository(application)
        allContactsForChat = chatRepository.getAllContactsForChat();
    }

Initialization of chatRepository ?
Also paste the code of line no: ChatActivity.java:168

Comment: i have posted chatRepository too kindly read the whole quesiton from top to bottom

Comment: @parthpatibandha the problem is not the line number 168. The problem is that the onChanged is not called inside onCreate synchronously and values are not assigned inside onChanged. The errors are result of that.